# Deleting duplicate records iterative

Tags: sql, postgresql

For each user_id (group) in a table I want to delete all records except the records with the highest ID in each group. Something similar to this: [Delete all records except the most recent one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238983/delete-all-records-except-the-most-recent-one)

In my case it would look like:

```
DELETE FROM logins
WHERE user_id IS NOT NULL AND id NOT IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM logins WHERE user_id IS NOT NULL GROUP BY user_id)
```

The problem is, the table holds 100+ millon records, so doing this in a single query like that would be impossible performance wise.

What other ways could I do this, e.g. in some batches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be inclined to phrase the `delete` as:

```
DELETE FROM logins l
    WHERE l.user_id IS NOT NULL AND
          l.id <> (SELECT MAX(l2.id)
                   FROM logins l2
                   WHERE l2.user_id = l.user_id
                  );
```

This can easily take advantage of an index on `logics(user_id, id)`.  However, if you are deleting a lot of rows, it is often better to truncate the table and recreate:

```
create table temp_logics as
    select l.*
    from logins
    where l.id = (SELECT MAX(l2.id)
                  FROM logins l2
                  WHERE l2.user_id = l.user_id
                 );

truncate table logins;

insert into logins
    select * from temp_logins;
```

If you take this approach, be sure to validate `temp_logins` before truncating the second table.  Actually, you do not want to use a temporary table for the intermediate table, because something might happen to the database -- and you would lose the data.

Comment: Are you sure the first query is doing the same as mine (preserving the largest ID for each group of user_id)? Also, would that one be suitable for deleting one million records+ at a time?

Comment: @NielsKristian . . . The first is deleted all but the largest id for every `user_id`.

Comment: Thanks worked. Deleted a lot of data in batches first. Then I ran the first query, worked fine for +2m rows