# Delete unecessary time from selected early of time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've a table from SQL Server and I've managed to tidy up the data. How to make unselected time or delete the past time data. so just need early time.
So I use this query:

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.name,MIN(time)
FROM table1 
GROUP BY id, name,time
```

and I'm failing when I try query like this:

```
DELETE FROM table1
WHERE table1.date EXCEPT MIN(time)
```

this is my table:

```
Id_student  name    date
1   azhar       06:19:20  
1   azhar       06:30:30  
1   azhar       06:39:30  
1   azhar       06:40:30  
1   azhar       06:49:30
```

and this is expected finished table:

```
Id_student  name    date
1   azhar   06:19:20
```

[expected table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0mab.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete all records except the most recent one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238983/delete-all-records-except-the-most-recent-one)

Comment: ya, any other same problem like this?...thanks alot.. i try to find the question like that...

Answer (score -1):

You can first use your query that fetches the earliest time per id as subquery and then in a second step delete all other rows. Something like this:

```
WITH earliest AS
  (SELECT id, MIN(time) AS eTime
  FROM table1 
    GROUP BY id)
DELETE FROM table1 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1 FROM earliest WHERE id = table1.id AND table1.time = eTime);
```

See this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zS2Cb7Q5). It shows this will work correctly.

Comment: `(NOT) IN` does not support tuples on the left side, and does not support multiple columns on  right hand side. The syntax is `<scalar expression> (NOT) IN {(<Scalar Expression 1>| , <Scalar Expression 2>|, <Scalar Expression N>) | (<Sub query returning single column>)}`

Comment: @ThomA You are right, sorry. I fixed it.